# Pass class instance C++

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ by programming a game. I'm using SDL to display my objects and a factory structure to keep it all organised.
I separated the first object (a car), the controls (keyboard) and the display (monitor).
In my main class I call the monitor class to display a window where I should draw the images. If a key is pressed, the car should react to that by redrawing the image.
The problem here is that I initialized the monitor in the main class and I can't access it in my car class..
I tried a variety of things, but nothing seems to do the trick.

So here is the main class

```
Game::Game(GuiFactory* factory) {

    bool is_running = true;

    Car* car = factory->createCar();
    car->drawCar();

    // create factory specific window
    Monitor* monitor = factory->createMonitor();

    // create factory specific keyboard
    Keyboard* keyboard = factory->createKeyboard();

    while (is_running) {
        // keyboard input
        string key_input = keyboard->getKeys();
        if (key_input == "quit") {
            is_running = false;
        } else if (key_input != "") {
            if(key_input == "right"){
                car->turnRight(monitor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a main car class and an SDLCar class, which inherits car.

```
class Car {
public:
    Car();
    virtual ~Car();
    virtual void drawCar() = 0;
    virtual void turnRight() = 0;
};
```

Here is where I'm confused:

```
class SDLCar : public Car {
public:
    SDLCar();
    virtual ~SDLCar();
    void drawCar();
    void turnRight(SDLMonitor& monitor);
    //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Could someone please explain?

Comment: Monitor is a pointer. Dereference it to get a reference. Is that the problem? Btw how do you delete car?

Comment: `car->turnRight(*monitor);` should do the trick.

Comment: It's not clear what about the underlined line is causing confusion. Is it just that you have a pointer in the main function while the method takes a reference, leading to compiler errors?

Comment: `Car::turnRight()` is a function that takes no parameters. `SDLCar::turnRight(SDLMonitor& monitor` does not match this signature. Referring to an instance of `SDLCar` as a `Car` will not allow you to call `turnRight(SDLMonitor& monitor)`, it will only accept `turnRight()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `car->turnRight(*monitor);` generates the error: `no matching function for call to 'CarGame::Car::turnRight(CarGame::Monitor&)'`

Comment: @sth I don't really know how I should pass an instance of a class to another object. And also because this generates compiler errors.

Comment: Can you write an example a few lines long which shows the type of code you are having problems with?

Comment: @Barto So isn't `CarGame::Monitor` derived from `SDLMonitor`? You need to show a complete minimal sample of your code.

Comment: Using the [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) keyword would have prevented this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In your base class `Car` you have declared the method `turnRight` **which takes *no* parameters**.

In your derived class `SDLCar` you have declared a *completely different* method with the same name. The reason why it's a different method and not a function *override* is that its takes a **parameter**. It should be parameterless to override `Car::turnRight`.

And because it's not a function override, the rules of polymorphism don't apply. Thus you can't call `SDLCar::turnRight(SDLMonitor&)` from a `Car` pointer.

---

**Right now** is an excellent time to start using the [*`override` keyword*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override). It prevents specifically these kind of programming errors. By marking a function with `override`:

```
void turnRight(SDLMonitor& monitor) override;
```

the compiler will automatically check that it *actually overrides* a function from the base class.

E.g. with the above declaration, the compiler would give you an error (or a warning at least). This would've helped you find your error right away and prevented more erroneous code such as `car->turnRight(monitor)`.

---

So now that the error is found, you need to find a way to fix it. Either declare the base class `turnRight` to take a `SDLMonitor&` as well, or think of something else if that's not how it should behave.

IMO having to pass the game window to a method like `turnRight` seems weird. Why would turning a car need a window? I think `turnRight` should do just what it says on the tin: turn the car right. Nothing else.

I don't know why you're passing a window to the method but if it's for drawing, shouldn't the `drawCar` method handle that? I don't know your code, so I'll leave it up to you.